Obtaining TOV equations
I am trying to obtain the first TOV equation
$$
(\rho+p) \frac{\mathrm{d} \Phi}{\mathrm{d} r}=-\frac{d p}{\mathrm{~d} r}
$$
using the metric
$$
\mathrm{d} s^2=-\mathrm{e}^{2 \Phi} \mathrm{d} t^2+\mathrm{e}^{2 \Lambda} \mathrm{d} r^2+r^2 d \Omega^2
$$
I have obtained the energy tensor components $T_{tt} = \rho e^{2 \Phi}, T_{rr} = p e^{2\Lambda},...$ so I know that I have to use $T^{r \beta}_{;\beta} = 0 $ but:
$$
T^{rt}_{;t} + T^{rr}_{;r} + T^{r\theta}_{;\theta} + T^{r\varphi}_{;\varphi} = 0
$$
do not seems the correct expression, it implies a lot of terms not equal to the previous solution.
I would really appreciate any clue to solve this.

You need to use Einstein's equations. They'll give relations between your metric functions ($e^{2\Phi}$, $e^{2\Lambda}$) and the energy momentum components that you'll be able to solve for $\Lambda$ and $\frac{d\Phi}{dr}$. Then, you should be able to regroup the terms in $T^{r\beta}_{;\beta}$ and obtain the first TOV equation.
